# Fire notification every week in Android

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, periodic-task

I'm trying to make a notification in Android that shows up weekly on a selected day, 9:40am. When the user presses on this notification, it should take him to the fragment activity, how can I accomplish that?

My current code:

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
TextView tt;
final static int WEEK_Id=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String[] Categories = { "one","2","three"};
    tt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.oooo);
    tt.setText(Categories[WEEK_Id]);

    // 8 AM Each day
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Receiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(am.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), am.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);
}
}
```

And receiver code:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
static final int reqCode=0;

public Receiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    showNotification(context);
}

public void showNotification(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, reqCode, intent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.food_recycleview)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("one");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(reqCode, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only time your alarm will go off would if you visit the activity before 9:40 am, otherwise you are giving the alarm a moment int the past.

For the alarm manager to go off at a certain moment, it has to be a moment in the FUTURE, and from then it will be repeating.

So you have to instantiate the calendar, set its time to the next 9:40 in the future, and then set the Alarm

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
//verify if the current time is past 9:40, then add one day
if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) > 9 
        || (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 9 && calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) >= 40))
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

//Then when placing the intent for the alarm, you have to add an action so your broadcast receiver can filter it

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Receiver.class);
intent.setAction("com.name.package.ACTION_FOR_ALARM");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(am.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), am.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);
```

In your Broadcast Receiver you have to check for the action of the incoming intent

file : MyBroadcastReceiver.java

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    //recibo la alarma
    if(action.contains("com.name.package.ACTION_FOR_ALARM")){
        [...]   // <-- your code for the notification
    }
 }
```

And dont forget to register the filter in your broadcastreceiver in the manifest, so your app can filter your intent action:

```
<application>

    [...]

    <receiver android:name="MyBoradcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.name.package.ACTION_FOR_ALARM" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: on clicking notification take me to fragment activity did you know any thing about it??

Comment: I dont see any problem with your code (didnt try it though), have you got any problem while debbuging? or an error? or it just simply does nothing when you press the notification?